# Issue with vector iterator when char is used

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, iterator

I'm having some issues here. I'm creating a matrix of two vectors, but there's an issue with the findVertex method.

```
namespace GraphNameSpace
{
  template <class T>
  class Graph
  {
  public:
    Graph<T>();

    void createMatix();
    void insertVertex(T Vertex);
    int findVertex(T Vertex) const;

  private:
    vector<vector<int> > matrix;
    vector<T> objectsVert;

  };
}


template <class T>
void GraphNameSpace::Graph<T>::insertEdge(T fromVertex, T toVertex, int weight=1)
{
  if(dir == UNDIRECTED)
  {
    matrix[findVertex(toVertex)][findVertex(fromVertex)] = weight;
    matrix[findVertex(fromVertex)][findVertex(toVertex)] = weight;
  }
  else
    matrix[findVertex(fromVertex)][findVertex(toVertex)] = weight;



template <class T>
int GraphNameSpace::Graph<T>::findVertex(T Vertex) const
{
  for(typename vector<T>::iterator it = objectsVert.begin(); it < objectsVert.end(); it++)
  {
      if(*it == Vertex)
      {
          return it - objectsVert.begin(); 
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

***********************IN MAIN*************************

```
int main()
{
   Graph<char> Graph3(DIRECTED,WEIGHTED);

   char A = 'A';
   Graph3.insertVertex(A);
   Graph3.insertEdge(A,B,5);
}
```

The problem seems to stem from whenever a char is used, as it gives me this error:

conversion from ‘std::vector >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >}’ requested

Comment: Inside `findVertex` change: `vector<T>::iterator` to `vector<T>::const_iterator`

Comment: Thank you so much, I've just been tearing my hair out.